# android gridview lag on scroll

Tags: android, gridview, scroll

I'm programming an app that has a grid view with some images, and I'm using the default vertical scroll, since not all the images can be fit into the screen. Alway I do scroll, and there is a new line to show, there seems to be a lag, on the render of the new row.

All the images are drawables, so it is not cause by something like loading the image, at least, not explicitly. So, any ideads of how to solve the problem? The scrolling is lagged in my atrix, and the final devices the app is supposed to run in, are far worse than it.

**Edit - Here some code:**

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    T item = getItem(position);
    Box box = convertView == null ? new Box(mContext) : (Box) convertView;
    onBindModel(box, item);
    return box;
}
```

and

```
@Override
public void onBindModel(Box box, Model item) {
    box.param.putSerializable("model", item);
    box.setDescricao(item.getNome());
    box.getModelImageView().setImageResource(item.thumbResId);
}
```

**Edit**

So, as suggested, just tried this code, but still get the same results:

```
@Override
public void onBindModel(final Box box, final Model item) {
    box.param.putSerializable("model", item);
    box.setDescricao(item.getNome());

    new Thread(){
        public void run() {
            Message msg = new Message();
            msg.obj =box.getModelImageView();
            msg.arg1 =item.thumbResId; 

            mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
        }
    }.start();
}

 private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) {
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),  message.arg1);
        setImage((ImageView) message.obj,bm);
    }
};

public void setImage(ImageView imgView, Bitmap bm) {
    imgView.setImageBitmap(bm);
}
```

When scroll to the next line I got a hang and then it just continues normally.

Thanks in advance

Comment: could you post your code. there can be many reasons for this.

Comment: Have you solved your problem? i am having the same problem. Images are loaded from the server and decoded on separate thread, i just do setImageBitMap on UI-THread and it still lags a bit...

Comment: Not really, in fact, I ended up changing the UI design, and in the new design I have created several pages, using several grids. When paging, I swipe the whole grid apart. But the code I posted on edit indeed loads the images in a better way, not blocking the load of the activity/fragment, and I'm using the handler approach for the rest of the app.

Answer (score 1):

> All the images are drawables, so it is not cause by something like
>   loading the image, at least, not explicitly.

This is not true. The work is done on the UI thread. 
Refer to 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource(int)

You might want to consider lazy loading the images. Multiple approaches have been discussed extensively everywhere. Google for it.

Answer (score 0):

Old question,but it did the trick :

```
 Glide.with(context)
            .load(stickersData[position])
            .into(imageView);
```

Using [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)